# find all occurrences between 2 values in non default pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am stumbling into an issue with a regex search in python

So I have:

```py
testVariable = re.findall(r'functest(.*?)1', 'functest exampleOne [2] functest exampleTwo [1] functest exampleOne throw [2] functest exampleThree [1]')
```

Current Output is:

```
[' exampleOne [2] functest exampleTwo [', ' exampleOne throw [2] functest exampleThree [']
```

But what I want is to find all occurences between ‘functest’ & 1' <or 2, or 3 based on need> so output should be like:

```
['exampleTwo [, exampleThree [']
```

this because both above are between functest & 1 as I need. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can not be any digits in between matching the first occurrence of 1 or 3:

```
\bfunctest\b\s*(\D*)[13]\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bfunctest\b\s*` Match the word functest followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(\D*)` Capture Optional non digits in group 1
- `[13]` Match either 1 or 3
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JfLCxM/1).

Or you can exclude matching the square brackets before matching a digit using a negated character class:

```
\bfunctest\b\s*([^][]*\[)[13]]
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBRUVC/1).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\bfunctest\b\s*([^][]*\[)239]"

s = "functest exampleOne [2] functest exampleTwo [239] functest exampleOne throw [2] functest exampleThree [1] functest exampleFour [2] functest exampleFive [239]"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['exampleTwo [', 'exampleFive [']
```

Comment: That works, but how should it look if instead of functest and 1 I need between functest and 2 and so on? –

Comment: @MarcelOlaru Then you can use an alternation if you can also have 2 or more digits `\bfunctest\b\s*([^][]*\[)(?:[13]|99)]` https://regex101.com/r/TnkzAE/1

Answer (score 0):

Found a way by using the following. It still includes functest, but at least does the job

testVariable = re.findall(r'functest(?:(?!functest).)*?239', 'functest exampleOne [2] functest exampleTwo [239] functest exampleOne throw [2] functest exampleThree [1] functest exampleFour [2] functest exampleFive [239]')

Output:
['functest exampleTwo [239', 'functest exampleFive [239']

Comment: You can use a capture group with re.findall like this example https://ideone.com/tZrtSl I have updated the answer I posted. If you want to use your pattern, you can write it like this `\bfunctest\b((?:(?!functest).)*?\s*\[)239]` https://regex101.com/r/YZjfr3/1 and then use it like this https://ideone.com/S8H4FC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).